# Show S is an invariant subspace of B

Tags: matrices

Suppose $B = \begin{bmatrix} X & 0 \\ Y & I \end{bmatrix} \in \Re^{nxn}$ with $X \in \Re^{sxs} $and$ ||X|| < 1$

Show $S =span\{e_{s+1},. . ., e_n\}$ is an invariant subspace of $B$ and that $B$ has a least $n - s$ eigenvalues equal to $1$ with $n > s$.

Find spectral radius of $B$ and $B^k$ ($k \ge 1$).

I think I need to show that $x \in S \Rightarrow Bx \in S$ but I am unsure how to.

I think the spectral radius of $B$ will be $1$ as  $p(X) \lt 1$ and $B$ is lower diagonal with $X$ on the diagonal and $p(I) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do that : for the invariance property, notice that $B(e_k)=e_k,  \forall k\geq s+1$, and conclude the invariance using linear combinations. These $n-s$ vectors are eigenvectors of $B$ with eigenvalues 1. Hence we can also conclude that $\rho(B)\geq 1$ (since 1 is an eigenvalue). Now write a vector of $R^n$ as a pair $(u,v)$ with $u\in R^s$ and $v\in R^{n-s}$. Suppose $u\neq 0$. This will be an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ iff $u$ is an eigenvector of $X$ (with eigenvalue $\lambda$) and $Yu+v=\lambda v$. But $\lambda$ being an eigenvalue of $X$, we have $\lambda\leq 1$ (since $\rho(X)$ is related to the norm of powers of $X$). Hence vectors of this form don't increase the spectral norm of $B$. Those with $u=0$ are in $S$ and there we know all eigenvalues, namely 1. So $\rho(B)=1$. The same conclusion applies to powers of $B$ because these powers have the same form as $B$.